# How to disable sorting while editing in DataTable

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, datatable, wpfdatagrid

In a WPF application i have a datagrid bound to a datatable, I sort a column in ascending. Now when i edit values in that particualr column, the values will be sorted(AS Sorting is already applied). Is there any way to prevent sorting on edit?

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information in your question to give a more detailed answer but something like this may work for you.

```
theColumnYouAreTargetting.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
```

You can disable the sorting during your edit and then enable it after you are done.